# Beacons - Smart Devices (Genexus 17)

Tags: android, genexus

estoy usando el Beacons External Object y no encuentro como hacer la lógica para poder detectar TODOS los beacons que se encuentren dentro del radio de detección del SD.

Alguien tiene experiencia en esto? Me podría decir cómo sería la secuencia de comandos para lograrlo?

Saludos y gracias!

Comment: Imagino que esto es lo que estas buscando? El metodo "getBeaconsInRange()": https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?27062,GetBeaconsInRange%C2%A0method

Comment: Si, lo probé a ese, pero no restorna nada. Y encontré esto en un SAC que quizás explica mi problema. https://www.genexus.com/en/developers/websac?data=49331;;

Comment: Sin embargo encontré que eso supuestamente se resolvió en el u3 de la versión 17. No estaría sabiendo porque no retorna nada entonces!